# Traversing Linux soft links using BASH

Tags: linux, bash

If i have 5 files in a directory (file1 - file5), lets say 5 is linked to 4 is linked to 3 is linked to 2 is linked to 1 (the original file), how would one go about reading any file and traversing the links to the original file? dont necessarily need code, just some ideas to get on the right track would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you extrapolate on 'traverse'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `stat` the file to check if it's a link . If the result is +ve , use "`readlink -f`" to get its full path.

For example

```
> tree
.
├── 1
├── 2 -> 1
├── 3 -> 2
├── 4 -> 3
├── 5 -> 4

> file="5"; \
while [[ -L $file ]]; \
  do echo -n "$file -> "; \
  file="$(readlink "$file")"; \
done; \
[[ -e $file ]] && echo "$file"
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

Comment: `stat` is hard to use programmatically (or, rather, hard to use programatically from portable code) -- much better to use `test -L "$file"`. That said, there's no reason to test before using readlink -- it returns a reasonable result on non-link files.

Comment: ...and if this were a question about interactive use rather than a question about scripting, it would belong on Superuser rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah you are right. One can use test too and then with readlink you wont have to keep traversing from one link to other. It will directly let you know the path of the original file.

Comment: Added example of what I think you and @CharlesDuffy were discussing in comments. (seemed close enough to not post as a separate answer, feel free to delete if you don't think it's helpful). Probably feels like a SU question to me too, though not terribly clear what's meant by traverse.

Comment: yes i see the readlink -f does the job, but that gives me the original path of the file immediately. Is there a way to actually see all the links in between?

Comment: @noobcoder Example in the post should give you that. If you were wanting to use it for anything useful I guess you would also probably want to add some check of whether the final file is a regular file/directory/doesn't exist, which you can just do by adding some more test operators.